# What happens when you restart a spark job if it encounters unexpected format in the data fed to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a question regarding Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka. 
Suppose that I am running a spark job and every thing is working perfectly. 
One fine day, my spark job fails because of inconsistencies in data that is fed to kafka. Inconsistencies may be anything like data format issues or junk characters which spark couldn't have processed. In such case, how do we fix the issue? Is there a way we can get into the kafka topic and make changes to the data manually?

If we don't fix the data issue and restart the spark job, it will read the same old row which contributed to failure since we have not yet committed the checkpoint. so how do we get out of this loop. How to fix the data issue in Kafka topic for resuming the aborted spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid trying to manually change one single message within a Kafka topic unless you really know what you are doing.

To prevent this from happening in the future, you might want to consider using a schema for your data (in combination with a schema registry).

For mitigating the problem you described I see the following options:

- Manually change the offset of the Consumer Group of your structured streaming application
- create a "new" streaming job that starts reading from a particular offset

### Manually change offset

When using Sparks structured streaming the consumer group is automatically set by Spark. According to the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L124) the Consumer Group will be defined as:

```scala
val uniqueGroupId = s"spark-kafka-source-${UUID.randomUUID}-${metadataPath.hashCode}"
```

You can change the offset by using the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool. First identify the actual name of the consumer group by

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

and then set the offset for that consumer group for a particular topic (e.g. offset 100)

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --execute --reset-offsets --group spark-kafka-source-1337 --topic topic1 --to-offset 100
```

If you need to change the offset only for a particular partition you can have a look at the help function of the tool on how to do this.

### Create new Streaming Job

You could make use of the Spark option `startingOffsets` as describe in the [Spark + Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> **Option:** startingOffsets
>
> **value:** "earliest", "latest" (streaming only), or json string """ {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}} """
>
> **default:** "latest" for streaming, "earliest" for batch
>
> **meaning:** The start point when a query is started, either "earliest" which is from the earliest offsets, "latest" which is just from the latest offsets, or a json string specifying a starting offset for each TopicPartition. In the json, -2 as an offset can be used to refer to earliest, -1 to latest. Note: For batch queries, latest (either implicitly or by using -1 in json) is not allowed. **For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.** Newly discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.

For this to work, it is important to have a "new" query. That means you need to delete your checkpoint files of your existing job or create complete new application.

Comment: Mike, I don't think the second option you suggested to use startingOffsets will be helpful.
Since my job is a resuming job after a failure occurred, it would still pick up from where it left off. 1st option you suggested will work. can you help me how to find the partition and offset information of a particular row and filter the row coming from kafka based on partition?

Comment: The second option will work if you delete your checkpoint files. That is why I specifically highlighted the one sentence that you need a "new" query.

Comment: Hi @shankar, for the first option to work you can select "offset AS Long", similar on how you would select key and value. Read the provided link in my answer for more details. As soon as you have the offset in your Dataframe, you can apply regular filters :-)

Comment: topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1}

The above statment means, start reading Partition 0 from 23rd offset from TopicA and start reading partition 1 from latest offset from TopicA? Have i understood this correctly, Mike?